# TextBox Text disappear after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to make a GridView in asp.net with headers columns like this

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Date">
    <HeaderTemplate>                                      
        <asp:LinkButton ID="headerDate" runat="server" Text="Date ↕️" CommandArgument="Date" CommandName="Sort" ></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox  AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="bindFilteredList" ReadOnly="false" CssClass="search_textbox"  runat="server" ID="fitlerDate" > 
        </asp:TextBox>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Date") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My problem is that when a textbox is filled, my onTextChanged function is triggered, I do my tricks (the value in textBox still here), and the page refreshes itself and goes through the page_Load :

```
if (!IsPostBack && !IsAsync)
{
    this.mpePopUp.Hide();
    String defaultSortExpression;
    enuSortOrder defaultSortOrder;
    int defaultIndex;
    // On trie par date déscendant par défaut pour avoir les articles les plus récents
    defaultSortExpression = sortExpression[0];
    defaultSortOrder = enuSortOrder.soDescending;
    defaultIndex = 0;

    // bind data au gridview
    this.ViewState.Add(VS_CURRENT_SORT_EXPRESSION, defaultSortExpression);
    this.ViewState.Add(VS_CURRENT_SORT_ORDER, defaultSortOrder);
    this.ViewState.Add(VS_CURRENT_INDEX, defaultIndex);


    bindData(defaultSortExpression, defaultSortOrder, defaultIndex);
}
```

Although I don't fit into the if (checked with the debugger), at the end of the function, when the debugger is on the closing brace, my value disappears from the TextBox.

What can i do to keep the values in TextBox?

You need to know all of these :

- My GridView is in updatePanle
- My textboxes can't be reached in editor by Id or with

`TextBox tb = (this.TableArticles.HeaderRow.FindControl("filterDate") as TextBox);`

I don't know the reason like my IDs of textboxes didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the value of fitlerDate in ViewState in ontextchanged event. 
like

```
ViewState["fitlerDate"] = fitlerDate.Text;
```

And bind that value again while rebinding the grid after filtering.

You have to register GridView event `OnRowDataBound` and in that event you have to write logic to find header control like

```
protected void gvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                TextBox fitlerDate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("fitlerDate");
                if (fitlerDate != null)
                {
                    fitlerDate.Text = ViewState["fitlerDate"].ToString();
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: I would like to thank you. I didn't know these features that will be useful to me in the future.

I just want to add a few changes I made:
- I add in the !isPostBack function
`ViewState["filterDate"] = ""; ` . To avoid any problem with null pointer.